# vba date greater than in less than expression error

Tags: vba, ssrs-2008

Hi I have the following code

```
Public Function checkDate(ByVal SomeDate As String) As Integer
If CDate("Sep 24 2012") >= CDate(SomeDate) Then
     Return 1
End If
Return 0
End Function
```

When I call checkDate("January 1 2012"), or any date earlier than Sep 24 I get 1 returned.

However when I call checkDate("Sep 25 2012"), or any other date after Sep 24 I get #error returned.

Can someone explain why this happens instead of a 0 return value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VBA doesn't use Return

```
Public Function checkDate(ByVal SomeDate As String) As Integer
    If CDate("Sep 24 2012") >= CDate(SomeDate) Then
        checkDate = 1
    Else
        checkDate = 0
    End If
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

This code worked for me in VBA. I haven't check this for working in SSRS.

```
Public Function checkDate(ByVal SomeDate As String) As Integer
Dim dteCheck As Date
Dim dteSomeDate As Date

dteCheck = CDate("Sep 24 2012")
dteSomeDate = CDate(SomeDate)

If dteCheck >= dteSomeDate Then
    checkDate = 1
Else
    checkDate = 0
End If
End Function
```